# How to create a pandas dataframe cross tab / summary table / pivot with different calculations

Tags: python, pandas

Hi everyone I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
print(df):
TrxID       Price       Profit        Online      Satisfaction
###          10           10           Yes         25%
###          15           20           No          75%
###          18           -10           Yes         55%
###          10           30           No          70%
###          20           -50           Yes         79%
###          30           15           No          90%
###          30           15           No          15%
```

And I am hoping to create the following summary / cross tab / pivot table:

```
SatisfactionBins     SalesMade   AveSalePrice   CountofOnline    Profit      Profit/SalesMade     

20%                     1             30              0             15            1500%
40%                     1             10              1             10            1000%
60%                     1             18              1             -10           -1000%
80%                     3             15              1             0              0%
100%                    1             30              0             15            1500%
```

Is this the right way to go about it?

```
df['Profit/SalesMade'] = df['Profit'] / df['SalesMade']
probbins = [0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1]
df['SatisfactionBins'] = pd.cut(dfclubhouse['Satisfaction'],bins=probbins)
df.groupby('SatisfactionBins')[(df['SalesMade'].count()),(df['Price'].mean()), etc etc]
```

I'm hoping someone might be able to help with 'best practice' in how to code this but im not sure where to go from here. Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pd.cut` solution is correct , just need to change the `groupby`

```
df.groupby('SatisfactionBins').agg({'SalesMade':'count','Price':'mean'})
```

Comment: Thanks @YOBEN_S. I have them working for `count`, `mean` and `sum` but any ideas on how to get the `count` where `Online =='Yes'` as a column and then also how to apply a percentage calculation `df['Profit/SalesMade'] = df['Profit'] / df['SalesMade']` as a new column?